# Trying to capture the following string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture this string with regex. It doesn't appear to be generating any matches.

```
  $property = "[[resource:76e9e8b2-788a-407f-a285-4728be19f71f:";

  if(!is_array($property)) {
  preg_match("\[\[resource:(\w+-\w-\w-\w-\w):", $property, $matches);
  print_r($matches[1]);
  }
```

As far as I can tell, the alphanumeric sequence with dashes should be put out to the $matches variable - but in fact, when I print_r() that variable out, I get nothing.

So how do I get a match inside the $matches array.

Ultimately what I want to be able to get is this:

```
76e9e8b2-788a-407f-a285-4728be19f71f
```

Comment: Where does this data come from? It looks like you just want to match a guid, which would be `/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a bunch of `+` modifiers. You also forgot the delimiters at the beginning and end of the regexp.

```
preg_match('/\[\[resource:(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+):/', $property, $matches);
                                 ^   ^   ^   ^
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't appear to be matching still, or at least, print_r($matches[1]); doesn't seem to echo it out.

Comment: You also forgot the delimiters, and apparently ignored the error this was causing.

Comment: The error didn't echo to my console. I should have probably checked the error log.

Comment: @Barmar, it looks like you forgot to escape your backslash characters for use within a string. It should probably be `"/\\[\\[resource:(\\w+-\\w+-\\w+-\\w+-\\w+):/"`

Comment: Yes. When programs don't work as expected, that's one of the first places I look.

Comment: @zzzzBov `\[` doesn't have any special meaning, so it's left alone and doesn't need to be escaped. I tested it and it works. However, I normally use single quotes around regexp to avoid the problem.

Comment: @Barmar, ``\`` characters are still used for escape sequences within single quoted strings. It's good practice to always use the correct escape sequence for the intended character (ie ``\\`` for the ``\`` character). I fully understand that `\[` is meaningless so the ``\`` is left as-is, but the regex could always change such that an actual string escape code is used (like `\t`, or `\$`) which could have unintended consequences.

Comment: @zzzzBov No, escape sequences are NOT processed in single-quoted strings. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: @Barmar, sure they are, just fewer of them ``\\`` and ``\'`` are both processed in single-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside comment, you can use the character class `[[:xdigit:]]` that fits exactly the hexadecimal characters:

```
\[\[resource:([[:xdigit:]]+(?>-[[:xdigit:]]+){4}):
```